# Auto pulled YouTube videos won't load in fancy box

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, fancybox

On my home page I have YouTube videos that get auto pulled via YouTube API. They display perfectly and the links come through as expected. They each have `class="fancybox-youtube"` but none of the videos open in a fancy box window.

I manually entered a link above the YouTube videos that auto feed and that works.

If you go to my home page 
[2k Online Franchise](http://www.2kolf.com/) and scroll down to "Latest Videos" you will see the videos I am referring to. You will also see text above those images that says "YouTube video link works".

Thank you in advance for the help, I have reserached this for hours and trouble shot it too but as you have read, it's beyond me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dreamed my answer! lol I fixed it. It was due to an old version of jquery running with the latest version of Fancy Box. I updated to jquery3.2.1 and it worked.